# jQuery event not attaching to the input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a field called as cellphoneDetails, I am trying to attach an invalid event to it, but it is not attaching the event to it

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById("contactEditForm");

  if (x.addEventListener) {
    var error = 0;
    alert('bingo');
    x.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
        alert('test test');
        $("##CellphoneDetails").on("invalid", function() {
          alert($(this).val());
          error = 1;
          if ($(this).val() != '') {
            $(this).focus();
            $("##cellValidDetails").css('display', 'block');
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

the HTML has the pattern added to it which validates if the value is entered, it should be a valid cellphone number else if its empty, do not validate it and move ahead

but due to some issue, the event is not attaching to the submit call and making a mess

Comment: You're adding an event listener, which adds an event listener when the event it listens for is triggered. This is rarely the correct thing to do. Also, your selectors have two `#` symbols, which is incorrect.

Comment: so what is the solution to it

Comment: Don't add the event listener in an event listener. Add the "invalid" event listener outside of the "submit". Use one `#` symbol.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I noticed is that it should be `$("#CellphoneDetails")`, not `$("##CellphoneDetails")`, and `$("#cellValidDetails")` instead of `$("##cellValidDetails")`.

To target and ID, you only need one `#`.

Also, I believe `(x.addEventListener)` will always be undefined.

You have a mix of JS and jQuery, I'd suggest just using one or the other primarily.

Comment: that is typo, its because i m using serverside, so its always use single #

Comment: i am willing to change, please guide me

Comment: OK! I'll look closer at this when I'm able. What is the purpose/goal/reason for this `if` statement? `if (x.addEventListener)`